# Is it possible to save mid-level progress?

Tags: monument-valley

I got badly stuck in the free Ida's Dream DLC (higher level of difficulty than in the entire base game as far as I can see, five or more puzzles) and would rather put the game on hold and resume later.

I once tried exiting a chapter and had to replay from the beginning.

Comment: I also suspect that's it's possible to reach unbeatable state (chapter 10), but I'm not sure.

Comment: As far as I am aware there is no unbeatable states in the game. I've played through both games numerous times and can't think of any point where this might be the case. If you wanted to ask with more detail though or posdt a state that you think it unbeatable then we might be able to be more definitive about this. My experience though is that anything you do in terms of manipulating the game world and moving around is always reversible (eg if you move somewhere then you can move back). Anything the game does to change the world only happens when you are in specific places so won't break things

Comment: @Chris: I'll try to reproduce after the holidays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not played the game in some time but last time I did there was no save option, if you loaded the game up fresh you'd need to start from the beginning. That having been said on my android phone if I leave the game without closing it then it will suspend and when I go back it will resume in the state I left it (eg mid level). I suspect that can't be guaranteed to stay in that suspended state indefinitely though so while it might be good for short breaks I suspect it isn't practical as a long term "save" technique.

That having been said my experience is that once I've worked out the tricks for a levels the next time I go through it it is much quicker to get to a given point so you may find that having to replay half a level is not actually as bad as you are worried it might be.